# Suggestion on MongoDB indexing

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, database

I have the following MongoDB schema 
Item

- id
- title : string
- description : string
- num_views : number
- num_likes : number
- num_unlikes : number
- val_trending : number
- val_rating : number
- timestamp : number

**val_trending** is calculated based on the value of **num_views, num_likes, num_dislikes, timestamp**

**val_rating** is calculated based on the value of **num_likes, num_dislikes, timestamp**

I have to query Items based on **num_views, val_trending** or **val_rating**

i.e.

- Item.find ().sort ({ val_trending : -1 }).limit (20)
- Item.find ().sort ({ num_views : -1 }).limit (20)

**num_views, num_likes and num_unlikes** are updated when a user **view**, **like** or **unlike** an Item accordingly

**val_trending** is updated when a user **view**, **like** or **unlike** an Item

**val_rating** is updated when a user **like** or **unlike** an Item

That’s a lot of updating and that's what got me worried. I thought of indexing **num_views, val_trending and val_rating** for faster results. But this will also show down updates.

I will be querying Items several times every second and updates will occur more frequently as user might also like or unlike an Item after viewing an Item.

So, my question is: what sort of implementation (indexing) should I do in order to get the best performance?

*Note: The DB will hold approximately 10K **Items** at start, and it will increase daily.*